# Team City not able to fetch source code from TFS for build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, teamcity

I know little about this, but it has fallen to be at work to look into. I know a really tiny bit about TFS, and a little less than that about Team City, but do have access to both.

I have a Team City project that watches for commits to a TFS repo. When someone checks in files, TeamCity fetches them, then builds the project and publishes it via web deploy to our 'Dev' environment. This process is much less automated for higher grade environments like UAT etc.

Now, suddenly about two weeks ago, someone changed something, and when do a build in TeamCity I get two error messages. The first seems more introductory, that there has been a problem:

> Failed to collect changes, error: Failed to get current version of TFS
>   root. TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server
>   applogix-projects.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection. Technical
>   information (for administrator): The remote name could not be
>   resolved: 'applogix-projects.visualstudio.com'

The second error message, displayed on the same screen as the first, is slightly more technical, and even includes a fairly verbose stack trace, which I will omit until clearly necessary. The 2nd message:

> Failed for the root '"Hollard - MLAM - Web" {instance id=4, parent
>   internal id=1, parent id=HollardMlamWeb_HollardMlamWeb, description:
>   "tfs: https://applogix-projects.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
>   $/Hollard - MLAM/HollardMLAM/Hollard.MLAM"}: Failed to get current
>   version of TFS root. TF400324: Team Foundation services are not
>   available from server
>   applogix-projects.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection. Technical
>   information (for administrator): The remote name could not be
>   resolved: 'applogix-projects.visualstudio.com'

Those remove names that cannot be resolved within Team City, e.g. `applogix-projects.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection` resolves fine when I paste it into a browser, and it directs me to our Visual Studio Online location for the project.

What I would appreciate as an answer here is an overview how the TFS fetch and TC build basically occur, and then some settings in TeamCity and or VS Online TFS that could be causing something like this.

It might be worth noting that if I pull the 'official' publish profile for Dev, and manually straight from VS Publish wizard, the app builds OK is well deployed to the Dev environment.

Comment: Does your build server have internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check VCS settings in your teamcity build. Follow below steps:

**Go to Edit Configuraton settings**

[image]

**Click on Version Control Settings**

[image]

**Check TFS URL and other settings**

[image]
Check [Configuring VCS Roots](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Roots) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If the credentials are incorrect then Visual Studio Online will report that it does not exists to prevent hackers.

Tge most likely issue is that the credentials are invalid. You should check that the user still exists and has the correct permission. You may have to use the "alternative credentials" from a users profile.

You can use the TFS Credential Viewer to get master unattended credentials for your VSO account, however these are the keys to the kingdom, so protect them.